# Why am I getting a segmentation fault when using fgets and sscanf in a for loop?

Tags: c

The goal of this is to enter in 8 integers and then print the sequence backwards. When I run this I am able to enter one integer before I am given a seg fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int eight[8];
int i;
char s[100];
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    printf("Please enter an integer \n");
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(s, "%d", eight[i]);
}
for(; i > 0; i--){
    printf("%d", eight[i]);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Because eight[i] is not a valid pointer to an int?

Comment: You should be testing the return value of `fgets()` to make sure it actually read a line and didn't get EOF or an error instead.  You should be testing the return value of `sscanf()` (ensure that it is 1) so you know whether the string entered could be interpreted as a number.  (But your problem is what @immibis says: you need `&eight[i]` and not `eight[i]` in the call to `sscanf()`.)

Comment: I tried it with &eight[i] in the sscanf call and it still gives a seg fault. Also, I'm new so I'm not exactly sure how to test the return value.

Comment: @HoneyBunchers 1) Insure you applied `&` here `sscanf(s, "%d", &eight[i]);` and not  `printf("%d", eight[i]);`.  2) enable all compiler warnings to save time.

Comment: testing the returned value from `scanf()`   `if( sscanf(s, "%d", &eight[i]) != 1 )  { fprintf( stderr, "sscanf failed to extract an integer\n" ); }`

Comment: at this point: `for(; i > 0; i--){`  the variable `i` will contain 8.  when indexing into an array (in C) the valid indexes are (0...number of entries in array -1 )  so the first loop execution will be accessing beyond the end of the array `eight[]`  resulting in undefined behavior.  Suggest: for(i =7; i >= 0; i--){

Comment: Okay sorry guys I think I forgot to recompile when I added the &. Thanks for the help everyone it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sscanf() you have to give a pointer to the variable in which you want to store the value; `sscanf(s, "%d", &eight[i]);`.

This https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm page says:

> other arguments − This function expects a sequence of pointers as additional arguments, each one pointing to an object of the type specified by their corresponding %-tag within the format string, in the same order.
>
> For each format specifier in the format string that retrieves data, an additional argument should be specified. If you want to store the result of a sscanf operation on a regular variable you should precede its identifier with the reference operator, i.e. an ampersand sign (&), like: int n; sscanf (str,"%d",&n);

The segmentation fault occurs because instead of a valid pointer, sscanf() gets the value of `eight[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Along with your third sscan parameter being incorrect (change to &eight[i]), your for-loop for printf has incorrect start/end points.

After your first for-loop, i=8, and this is the first value you test for in the printf for-loop.  But i=8 is out of bounds of the array.

Also, you end on i=1, but you want to go all the way to i=0.

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int eight[8];
int i;
char s[100];
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    printf("Please enter an integer \n");
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(s, "%d", &eight[i]);
}
//i=8 at this point, out of bounds
i--;
for(; i >= 0; i--){  //changed to >= (we want to check when i==0)
    printf(" %d ", eight[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```